# How to stop RubyMine/WebStorm from including node_modules when using 'find in path'

Tags: node.js, webstorm, rubymine

I have a node.js project which, after running `npm install` has a `node_modules` folder in the project root. Everything works fine, but when I load the project into RubyMine, right-click on the project root folder and choose `find in path...`, the search includes all of the code inside `node_modules`, which is not useful.

I have tried to mark the `node_modules` folder as 'excluded', which works, but it still includes the contents in the search.

How can I get `find in path...` to only search my project files?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create [custom scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/scopes.html?search=scope) (can be accessed directly in `Find in Path` dialog (by clicking on `...` button) or via `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes`): include all and then exclude unwanted folders recursively (or just include desired folders only).
2. Choose that scope in `Find in Path` dialog

   [image]

   *NOTE: Screenshot and settings path is from PhpStorm but it should be the same in RubyMine as well (it's platform-wide feature).*

**P.S.**
You can use the same approach in TODO window -- to only show TODOs from your own files.

---

Excluded folders should not be searched (works OK with ordinary excluded folders) -- possibly it's because they are also listed as JavaScript (or any other) libraries and at the same time located within the content root?

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst this does exclude node_modules, it then includes all of the gem folders, which causes the same problem :/

Comment: So .. have you tried excluding gem folders as well (in addition to the node_modules)?

Comment: Yeah, the gem folders don't appear in the list of excludable folders :(

Comment: In such case I do not understand how such files gets listed in search results if custom scope is used. Maybe folder is "hidden"; maybe you should add pattern even if it's not listed in the list?