# How can I prevent TODOs from node_modules packages showing up in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I was trying to use the TODO window from WebStorm (or any other JetBrains IDE), but I get tons of TODOs from `node_modules`:

[image]

So in this way, this feature is not really useful. When I exclude the `node_modules` folder from the project, the TODOs go away, but also the autocompletion from those modules etc, so I don't think this is really the way to go.

How can I make sure those TODOs from `node_modules` are not shown?

Comment: Sure: 1) Create custom Scope and list there only real project files 2) use that scope in TODO window (instead of "Project Files"). Check these SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14901722/783119 ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/34614431/783119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like Webstorm fixed this itself after restarting Webstorm, I saw my node_modules where listed as 'library root'. I suppose this is a bug where node_modules are not listed as library on creating a new project.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution if it didn't get fixed by magic (I assume plugin did that for your case) :

- Press Alt + 6 (default bind for TODO)
- Click on "Scope based" tab
- Change the "Scope" by clicking on the button with three dot
- Choose what directory you want to exclude in recursive way or not.
- ???
- Enjoy